# Model doesn't get updated when back to Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Models is populated within the ctor.
When I click Edit to edit an item ,it all works, and I can clearly see that the Model has been updated within Models after the TryUpdateModel() call.

However when its redirected to the index, Models doesn't have my changes any longer.  What happened?

```
        // GET: /Contact/    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Models);
        }


        // GET: /Contact/Edit/5    
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var contactModel = Models.Find((x) => x.ID == id);
            return View(contactModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var contactModel = Models.Find((x) => x.ID == id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(contactModel))
            {
               return RedirectToAction("Index");   
            }

            return View(contactModel);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you only changed the model in memory from the Edit call, but not saved the changes down to persistant storage (database), so your ctor is reloading it from an *unsaved* state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using to persist your models (saving them to a DB). In my case I ran into the same problem and I had to make sure that I called something along an `Update` or `Save` method prior to my redirect since my model session was scoped to the HTTP request, a redirect didn't cause my session to be flushed, and changes saved.

In my case I was using nHibernate, and ended up adding an attribute to that when an action was finished, I flushed my changes.

Answer (score 0):

The html helpers use ModelState by default on a post. It assumes if there hasnt been a redirect, there must have been an error so show the 'old' values.

You have to clear the modelstate (ModelState.Clear()) or come up with a different pattern : )